# Object cannot be nil for Un used NSUserDefaults key in project

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsexception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: client_id)

In my current project (Swift) I am getting the above error, even when I haven't used that key anywhere in the project. I got the error after Facebook integration.

But the same key was used in my previous project. To resolve this problem, I cleaned my build and even uninstalled both previous and current app and then rerun build. Still facing error.

I searched for the key access `client_id` in all files, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Try to find setObjectForKey in your project...

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @avinash you are not replied anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your Info.plist file for facebook SDK integration is not properly configured and saved.
For more detail refer FBSDK documentation
Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

in the breakpoints tab, add exception breakpoint and see where exception is being hit. It is most likely you are adding a nil value to a dictionary.

Comment: App crashes when I click on Facebook Login Button of facebook SDK integrated in app.

Comment: put the exception breakpoint and see where it breaks. You need to set this client_id somewhere (Appdelegate?) before you run the SDK. It is generally commented out.